# Issues with npm angular package

Tags: angularjs, npm

I am trying to figure out what exactly is the issue.

So I have a block of code that works with

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.5/angular.min.js"></script>
```

But is broken when I use the angular that I installed locally via NPM.

Now the NPM local version I am using is 1.3.5 and inside package.json its listed as

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "1.3.5"
  }
```

When I change my package.json to

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular": "^1.3.5"
  }
```

so it pulls down the most updated version I get this warning

```
npm WARN deprecated angular@1.3.36: bad package, use v1.3.5 instead
```

So I revert back to the 1.3.5 version....But it still doesnt work with my local copy of angular.

What am I doing wrong?

For ref this is an example of what I am doing http://jsbin.com/sibejocopi/1/

as you can see it updates the latest time but using my npm copy of angular it doesnt change.

Comment: What error are you seeing the the browsers console log? Saying " it still doesnt work with my local copy of angular. " is too generic. Are you serving the files from a web server locally? Is the path to the local angularjs correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you mean by "work[ing] with your local copy of angular".  Are you building a website or single-page app?  If so, you will want to use the "//ajax.googleapis.com/..." reference you quote above, since your users are more likely to have it in their browser cache.

Or are you trying to set things up so that you can work on your website offline?

In either case, I would need more information before I could answer this question.  How are you serving your files -- express? nginx?  What is your server configuration?  How are you specifying the path to the local `angular.min.js` when it doesn't work?  Have you looked at other package managers (such as `bower`) that are generally considered better suited for serving web assets?